# VB - Run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have created a `CommandButton` within Excel and started coding `VBA`.
The idea is to pass parameters to my `CommandString` so that the user can filter.

The 2 parameter fields are of datatype `smalldatetime` within `SQL`

Here is my VBA code which executes after I `Click` the `CommandButton` :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date

    FromDate = Sheets("Bips Travel Summary").Range("J3").Value
    ToDate = Sheets("Bips Travel Summary").Range("J4").Value

    'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("192.168.0.3 Timesheets1").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "SELECT ID, Employee,  WT, [Amount Per Kilometer], Currency, SUM([Number (Amount of km)]) AS [Number (Amount of km)], SUM([Total (per record)]) AS [Total (per record)] FROM ( SELECT S.ID ,S.FirstName + ' ' + S.LastName AS [Employee],TS.DateWorked AS [DateTraveled],C.Customer_Name,NULL AS [WT],EC.AA_Rate AS [Amount Per Kilometer],NULL AS [Currency],TS.Travel AS [Number (Amount of km)],TT.TravelDescription,TS.Travel * CONVERT(float, EC.AA_Rate) AS [Total (per record)] FROM [Timesheets].[dbo].[timesheets] TS INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[traveltype] TT ON TS.TravelTypeCode = TT.TravelTypeCode INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[staff] S ON TS.Staff_Code = S.Staff_Code INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[enginecapacity] EC ON TS.EngineCapacityCode = EC.EngineCapacityCode INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[customers] C ON TS.Cust_Code = C.Cust_Code WHERE TS.DateWorked BETWEEN '" & FromDate & "' AND '" & ToDate & "') as A GROUP BY ID, Employee, WT, [Amount Per Kilometer], Currency"
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("192.168.0.3 Timesheets1").Refresh

    End With
End Sub
```

After entering the value for `FromDate` as `20100101`
and `ToDate` as `20150813` I get an error message which falls over on this script:

```
FromDate = Sheets("Bips Travel Summary").Range("J3").Value
```

Error message reads :

```
Runtime error '13':
Type mismatch
```

Not sure where to go from here as I am very new to `VBA`.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to assign the wrong data type.

Variables `FromDate` and `ToDate` are declared as `Date` type, but you are trying to assign texts to them.

If you have dates in this format in your cells: '20100101' and '20150813', you need to convert them to dates before assigning to those variables like below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim txtFromDate As String
    Dim txtToDate As String
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date

    txtFromDate = Sheets("Bips Travel Summary").Range("J3").Value
    FromDate = DateSerial(Left(txtFromDate, 4), Mid(txtFromDate, 5, 2), Right(txtFromDate, 2))
    txtToDate = Sheets("Bips Travel Summary").Range("J4").Value
    ToDate = DateSerial(Left(txtToDate, 4), Mid(txtToDate, 5, 2), Right(txtToDate, 2))

    'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("192.168.0.3 Timesheets1").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "SELECT ID, Employee,  WT, [Amount Per Kilometer], Currency, SUM([Number (Amount of km)]) AS [Number (Amount of km)], SUM([Total (per record)]) AS [Total (per record)] FROM ( SELECT S.ID ,S.FirstName + ' ' + S.LastName AS [Employee],TS.DateWorked AS [DateTraveled],C.Customer_Name,NULL AS [WT],EC.AA_Rate AS [Amount Per Kilometer],NULL AS [Currency],TS.Travel AS [Number (Amount of km)],TT.TravelDescription,TS.Travel * CONVERT(float, EC.AA_Rate) AS [Total (per record)] FROM [Timesheets].[dbo].[timesheets] TS INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[traveltype] TT ON TS.TravelTypeCode = TT.TravelTypeCode INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[staff] S ON TS.Staff_Code = S.Staff_Code INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[enginecapacity] EC ON TS.EngineCapacityCode = EC.EngineCapacityCode INNER JOIN [Timesheets].[dbo].[customers] C ON TS.Cust_Code = C.Cust_Code WHERE TS.DateWorked BETWEEN '" & FromDate & "' AND '" & ToDate & "') as A GROUP BY ID, Employee, WT, [Amount Per Kilometer], Currency"
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("192.168.0.3 Timesheets1").Refresh

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I now get a different error which reads : The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in a out-of-range value. Any idea how I can get past this?

Comment: When I try to save the updated VBA, I get a error message : Application-define or object-defined error.