# copy data from one sheet and past it on another sheet of same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

[enter image description here][1]I want to copy range of 20-30 cells in row and paste those in another sheet. I made a program but facing errors of 424 and 1004. I was trying to solve this errors but couldn't, so I started to apply different tips from various site. But couldn't find any solution. I will appreciate your help. thanks

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
Dim copyrange As Range

Sheet3.Select
'where is my data lies
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastRow
    If cells(i, 1).Value = r Then
        ' condition that should satisfy

        copyrange = Range(Sheet3.cells(i, 8), sheete3.cells(i, 45)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Worksheets("sheet2").Select
        erow = ActiveSheet.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ' erow is last empty row where i wants to copy data

        ActiveSheet.cells(erow, 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: is it `Sheet3` ? or `Sheets("Sheet3")` ?

Comment: you are receiving this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985984/vb-run-time-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error and this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084686/excel-vba-run-time-error-424-object-required-when-trying-to-copy-textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnIiw.jpg)**First**, as a thumb rule, always define and set your Sheets, it will help you avoiding a lot of possible errors in the future.

I am not sure what is `r` in your code, in the line:

`If Sheet3.cells(i, 1).Value = "r" Then`

If it's a variable you defined before (not part of your attached code), then it will work. If you mean the letter "r" (a String) then you need to modify that line in this answer to :

```
If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "r" Then
```

Besides that, use the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()

Dim LastRow     As Integer, i   As Integer, erow    As Integer
Dim copyrange   As Range
Dim Sht3    As Worksheet, Sht2  As Worksheet

' always define and set your Sheets >> on the safe side

Set Sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("pending req")
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("recieve")

With Sht3
    'find last row with data
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow

        'If .Cells(i, 1).Value = r Then  ' condition that should satisfy (not sure what is r ? )
        ' use the line below to check if cell value equals "r"
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "r" Then

            Set copyrange = .Range(.Cells(i, 8), .Cells(i, 45))

            ' erow is last empty row where I want to copy data (assuming you meant Column A)
            erow = Sht2.Cells(Sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            ' copy a range from one sheet to another without Selecting or activating
            copyrange.Copy Sht2.Cells(erow, 3)
        End If
    Next i

End With

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Here "r" is string and i am getting error 9 at sht3. My bad its sheets("sheet3")

Comment: "r" is a variable representing a string ? Or u are comparing to see if it's "r" ?

Comment: @divy.h see edited code (added also the option that checks if cell value = "r")

Comment: Comparing to"r". I did saw edited code. But i am getting run time error "9" where you set sht3= thisworkbook.sheets.("sheet3").I am using excel 2007. @ShaiRado

Comment: you are not copying it right from my code, it's `Set Sht3 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")`

Comment: Added image of your code. But i think is problem is something else.

Comment: Are you sure you have "Sheet2" and "Sheet3"? There is no error in these settings, unless you don't have these sheets

Comment: From the attached image I'd say you have to change all "Sheet2" occurrences to "redeve" and all "Sheet3" ones to "pending req"

Comment: Code edited thanks to great observations by user3598756, I would never find it in that small left end corner.

Comment: can i copy two different range of the same row ? @shai rado

Comment: With Sht3
 LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "r" Then
 Set copyrange = .Range(.Cells(i, 4), .Cells(i, 5))
 Set cpyrange1 = .Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, 40))
 erow = Sht1.Cells(Sht1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 copyrange.Copy Sht1.Cells(erow, 3)
 copyrange1.Copy Sht1.Cells(erow, 10)

Answer (score 0):

Here cleaned it little bit

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, erow As long
Dim copyrange As Range

/* where is my data lies
LastRow = Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastRow
If Sheet3.cells(i, 1).Value = "r" Then         '<--- is r a string here ? put quotes if yes
/* condition that should satisfy

 erow = Sheet2.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
/* erow is last empty row where i wants to copy data

Set copyrange = Sheet3.Range(cells(i, 8), cells(i, 45))
copyrange.Copy Destination:= Sheet2.cells(erow, 3)

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: still having same problem. getting 1004 error at copyrange. I am using excel 2007. is it because of older version? Here "r" is a string